# mapstruct: map string parameter to a field

Tags: mapstruct

I'm trying to map a single `String` parameter to a field on target type:

```java
@Mapper(uses = ReferenceUniqueIdentifierMapper.class)
public interface NestedReferenceMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "referenceId", target = "referenceUniqueIdentifier")
    public NestedReference toDomainModel(String referenceId);
}
```

My target class is:

```java
public class NestedReference {

    private final ReferenceUniqueIdentifier referenceUniqueIdentifier;

}
```

I'm getting:

> No property named "referenceId" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "bytes"? Occured at 'NestedReference toDomainModel(String arg0)' in 'NestedReferenceMapper'.

Why it's telling me that `refereceId` doesn't exist if there's a defined `String referenceId` method parameter defined?

Any ideas?

Comment: It probably is looking for a property `referenceId` in the passed in `String`.